# TimeFrame Statistic Issue

Tags: php, statistics

I'm having a problem regarding a time frame statistic as you see here: http://www.ivao.ch/rfe_gva/stats . I don't know why but from 1200 to 1300z I've all the flight and this is not correct..I wanna see only the flight for that time..

```
<?php
for ($i=8;$i<18;$i++) {

    if ($i % 2 == 0) {
        echo "<div class=\"row margintop20\">";
    }

    if ($i >= 24) {
        $time = ($i-24)*100;
    } else {
        $time = $i*100;
    }
    $time100 = $time+100;
```

?>

How can i solve this problem?